# Django form field error: one character per error?

Tags: django, forms, field

Getting very strange output when I try to print out errors from a form. Here's my code in the template (using Bootstrap 3 in case you're curious about the CSS),

```
{% if not form.is_valid and form.is_bound %}    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-10 col-offset-1 text-center">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>

          {% for field in form %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
              <strong>{{ field.label }}</strong>: {{ error }} <br>
            {% endfor %}    
          {% endfor %}

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

 {% endif %}
```

All the other errors come out fine, except when I enter the wrong password. Then, I get an output like this,

```
Password: I 
Password: n 
Password: c 
Password: o 
Password: r 
Password: r 
Password: e 
Password: c 
Password: t 
Password: 
Password: p 
Password: a 
Password: s 
Password: s 
Password: w 
Password: o 
Password: r 
Password: d 
Password: , 
Password: 
Password: p 
Password: l 
Password: e 
Password: a 
Password: s 
Password: e 
Password: 
Password: t 
Password: r 
Password: y 
Password: 
Password: a 
Password: g 
Password: a 
Password: i 
Password: n 
Password: .
```

If you look closely, it's a sentence that says, "Incorrect password, please try again." Except every single character is getting its own line.

What's going on here?

For further reference, here's how I'm assigning error messages in the view,

```
form.errors['email'] = 'Email not found, please try again.'
form.errors['password'] = 'Incorrect password, please try again.'
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that the problem is the error loop is iterating through a string, which makes sense because you define it as a `string`.

```
form.errors['password'] = 'Incorrect password, please try again.'
```

Try it wrapping it in a list:

```
form.errors['password'] = ['Incorrect password, please try again.']
```

This may also happen with email.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks! Just curious, what do the brackets do? I'm a python n00b =)

Comment: @reedvoid wrapping anything inside brackets yield a list, ['a'] is a list with the string `a`, ['a','b'], a list with strings `a,b` :)

Comment: Thanks! That's kind of a weird behavior in Django's error message iteration. I only did that second layer of error iteration thing because it was the only way to remove the <ul> formatting they got. Django should really stop being so "smart" and try to format things for you.

Comment: form.errors['field'] is supposed to contain a list of error strings, not one error string.  Perhaps you should append to the list when you want to indicate you found an error, rather than assign to it (and potentially obliterate any other errors that might have already accumulated).  eg, `form.errors['password'].append ('Incorrect password, please try again')`